# Why is a form with a hash for the value being turned into an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a form that sends the following form data on form submit (gathered from the network tab in chrome):

```
purchase[status][special]:true
```

In the controller action that receives this create here is the code:

```
purchase = Purchase.new(status: params[:purchase])
purchase.save
```

In the database this is what gets created:

```
=> #<Purchase:0x007fd069693868
 @attributes=
  {"attributes"=>
    #<Purchase::Attributes:0x007fd06a16f6d8
     @attributes=
      {"name"=>"Toy Car",
       "status"=>
        #<Purchase::Attributes::ApiAnswers:0x007fd06a48f7f0
         @attributes={"special"=>"true"},
         @persisted=false,
         @prefix_options={}>,
```

Why is it creating a `Purchase::Attributes::ApiAnswers` object for status? All I want is a hash: `status => {"special" => "true"}`

Comment: Have you tried debugging what `params[:purchase]` actually is?

Comment: What does your Purchase model look like?